# Unable to use variable outside the function

Tags: node.js, koa

I am using Koa module - Node js and mysql & stuck on a problem.

In signup function (inside welcomeCtrl.js) I have:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
module.exports = {
signup: function* (next) {
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        console.log(salt);
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            // Store hash in your password DB. 
            console.log(hash); //no error
            var hashedPassword = hash;
        });
       });
        console.log(bcrypt.hash.hash); //gives error
             //or
        console.log(bcrypt.hash.hahedPassword); //gives error

        queryString = "insert into user(email,name, phone, password, course_id, dpt_id) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')";
        query = util.format(queryString, email, name, phone, hash, courseId, dptId);
        results = yield databaseUtils.executeQuery(query);
        this.redirect('/');
    }
   }
```

I am calling signup post function in different routes.js file as:

```
router.post('/signup', welcomeCtrl.signup);
```

Here is the `executeQuery` function in the `databaseUtils.js` file

```
 var executeQuery = function(query, callback) {
 pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    // Use the connection
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        connection.release();
        if(err) {
            err.mysqlQuery = query;
            logger.logError(err);
        }

        if(typeof callback == "function") {
            callback(err, rows);
        }
        // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
    });
});
};
 module.exports = {
executeQuery: thunkify(executeQuery),
executePlainQuery: executeQuery
};
```

Is there any way to use hash variable outside the function so that it can be inserted in query?

Answer (score 1):

You should move your query function into the callback for `bcrypt.hash`.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      console.log(salt);

      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in your password DB. 
        console.log(hash); //no error
        queryString = "insert into user(email,name, phone, password, course_id, dpt_id) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')";
        query = util.format(queryString, email, name, phone, hash, courseId, dptId);

        databaseUtils.executeQuery(query, function() {
          this.redirect('/');
        });
      });
    });
```

Problem is, where does your `redirect` function come from? You're going to loose context on `this` unless you bind the functions. Do fat arrow functions work in your setup? If so you could do it that way.

Comment: I tried that also but it throws error - Unexpected ,(comma) after results = yield databaseUtils.executeQuery(query);

Comment: Are you actually set up to use `yield`? If not you should probably fall back to classic promises. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes `yield` is all set up & sometimes I use yield this.render to render some html page, in this case no.

Comment: `results = yield databaseUtils.executeQuery(query).then(function () {","                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^","","SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier","    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)","` - again error

Comment: Ah I didn't see that your `signup` was a generator. Because you are using callback style functions from bcrypt, you might need something like https://github.com/pmuellr/yield-callback to use them with yields.

Comment: `var results = databaseUtils.executeQuery(query);
            console.log(results);` 
 Output without yield -> `[Function]`

Comment: Where does `databaseUtils.executeQuery` come from? Something you've written?

Comment: Yes `databaseUtils` is a js file and `executeQuery` is a function defined in it. I am serving this through main.js

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the source for that function?

Comment: Please vote up my Question so that it could be answered quickly